# Irmin Linked_log possible with Git.FS backend?

Tags: ocaml

I would like to use the `Linked_log` from `Irmin_containers`
https://mirage.github.io/irmin/irmin-containers/Irmin_containers/Linked_log/index.html

Two functors are provided for making a `Linked_log` backed by `Mem` or `FS` backends. Additionally a `Make` functor for making one fully configurably by passing all the args.

I would like to make one backed by a `Irmin_unix.Git.FS` store.

I am struggling to navigate the types and find the right values to pass to the various functors.

The existing Linked_log FS functor [looks like](https://github.com/mirage/irmin/blob/5fd54838c5e8eb9bfa4c02170df30698f78b0201/src/irmin-containers/linked_log.ml#L165):

```ml
module FS (C : Stores.Content_addressable) (V : Irmin.Type.S) () =
  Make (Irmin_unix.FS.KV) (C) (Time.Machine) (Irmin.Hash.SHA1) (V) ()
```

I think I just want to make my own "GitFS" functor that looks almost the same but substitutes `Irmin_unix.Git.FS.KV` for `Irmin_unix.FS.KV`

My first problem is `Stores.Content_addressable` type of `C` arg to the functor is found in this file:
https://github.com/mirage/irmin/blob/5fd54838c5e8eb9bfa4c02170df30698f78b0201/src/irmin-containers/stores.ml
...but it's not exported.

There's a convoluted series of includes to follow but I think I eventually found the right signature I can use in my own code. I was able to define:

```ml
module GitFSLinkedLog_maker (C : Irmin_containers.Cas_maker) (V : Irmin.Type.S) () =
  Irmin_containers.Linked_log.Make (Irmin_unix.Git.FS.KV) (C) (Irmin_containers.Time.Machine) (Irmin.Hash.SHA1) (V) ()
```

...and the type-checker is ok with that.

My problem now is how to use this functor.

I believe `V` should be something like `Irmin.Content.String`. I am lost what to pass for `C` though.

I thought I could look at their tests. For example [here](https://github.com/mirage/irmin/blob/2f0c1b3d4e7a8ba7c29c8fd33636eba6c399100b/test/irmin-containers/linked_log.ml#L21) they do:

```ml
module CAS = struct
  include Irmin.Content_addressable.Make (Irmin_mem.Append_only)

  let config = Irmin_mem.config ()
end

module L = Irmin_containers.Linked_log.Mem (CAS) (Irmin.Contents.String) ()
```

This looks promising. `Irmin_containers.Linked_log.Mem` is the equivalent of my `GitFSLinkedLog_maker`. So I need to pass a struct like that as the `C` arg.

But if I copy and paste that into my own code I get a build error:

```
51 |   include Irmin.Content_addressable.Make (Irmin_mem.Append_only)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: The module Irmin.Content_addressable is a functor, it cannot have any components
```

How does that work for them when it seems to be illegal code for me?

Comment: Well it seems like `Irmin.Content_addressable.Make` works for them because the internal interface is different from the external one, so `Irmin.Content_addressable` is a module for them but it's a functor for my code. I'm wondering if what I want to do is impossible :(

Comment: make sure that you have the right version as in the github version `Irmin.Content_addressable.Make` exists and is public.

Comment: I currently have latest `2.6.1` from opam. I will try head version from git